# If my product uses a certified RF transmitter, is it treated specially by the FCC?

Tags: fcc, certification

So I have a product. It uses the Particle P1 as the microcontroller and WiFi RF setup (with onboard antenna), which is pre-FCC certified; it has a ("Contains Transmitter") FCC ID that you put on the case of the final product. When I go to certify the entire product, do I still to get it tested as an intentional radiator? Does the fact that the "Intentional Radiator" portion is pre-certified make the device an unintentional radiator from a certification perspective?

Comment: Speak to the supplier. If they are selling it as a device that WILL pass tests if you do THIS or THAT then all you need to do is ensure you have applied the correct rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really the best way to get an answer to questions like these is to call your test house and just ask them, even if you are a first time customer they'll tell you things like this for free.

That said I wouldn't say you are treated as a unintentional radiator per se.  You just no longer have to do the intentional radiator testing as long as you are using the same antenna the module vendor used and following their integration guidelines.  This should save you plenty of cash on its own.